# unique_ptr deleter overhead

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, raii

In normal C++ design, most objects can be deleted either by a `delete` statement, the `free` function, or a library-specific equivalent to `free`. For such objects, the `unique_ptr` `Deleter` implementation can be a stateless object that is eliminated through Empty Base Class Optimization. However, some libraries require using another object (which might contain a function pointer or some other context) to delete objects from that library.

```
typedef struct lib_object lib_object;

struct lib_api {
  lib_object (*createInstance)();
  void (*freeInstance)(lib_object *o);
};
```

One could wrap this in `unique_ptr` by storing a `lib_api` pointer as a data member in a custom `Deleter`, but if multiple `lib_object` instances needed to be managed, e.g. in a container, it would double the memory overhead of tracking the objects. What kind of pattern can be used to maintain RAII principles when dealing with this library, while still remaining memory efficient?

Comment: Can you make the `lib_api*` a static member of the deleter class?

Comment: I think you need to store `freeInstance` in a custom derived class of the container class and that your container would contain `lib_object*`. In the derived class you have to implement the destructor that would call `freeInstance` on every element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is only ever one `lib_api` object, then you can have your deleter get a static pointer to it.

If there can be more than one `lib_api` object then you have no choice but to store a pointer to it in the Deleter.

Comment: I thought about this, and it seems global variables are the only useful solution.

Answer (score 2):

I use a custom deleter template for such objects.

```
template<typename T, T Function>
struct function_deleter
{
    template<typename U>
    auto operator()(U&& u) const noexcept(noexcept(Function(std::forward<U>(u))))
    {
        return Function(std::forward<U>(u));
    }
};
```

then you can have use your deleter call `free`:

```
unique_ptr<int, function_deleter<void(*)(void*), &free>> uniq;
```

And its size is still equal to one pointer. [live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/YbpW623K8A054dFa)

Come C++17 you'll be able to use `auto` for non-type template parameters, simplifying the code to:

```
template<auto Function>
struct function_deleter
{
    template<typename U>
    auto operator()(U&& u) const noexcept(noexcept(Function(std::forward<U>(u))))
    {
        return Function(std::forward<U>(u));
    }
};
```

and

```
unique_ptr<int, function_deleter<&call_free>> uniq;
```

[live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Ojq0BstjVKuCXJyv)

Having this, in your case I'd keep a `unique_ptr<pair<lib_object, lib_api>>` with static deleter supporting this structure.

```
using lib_pair = pair<lib_object, lib_api>;

void lib_free(lib_pair* p){
    p->second.freeInstance(p->first);
    delete p;
}


using unique_lib_ptr = unique_ptr<lib_pair, function_deleter<void(*)(lib_pair*), &lib_free>>
```

This seems more cache-heavy but might just be your thing.

Answer (score 0):

There should exist a more elegant solution but I would write something like

```
template <class ContainerType>
class TObjectContainer : public ContainerType {
  public:
   TObjectContainer() = default;
   TObjectContainer(const TObjectContainer&); // should call createCopy 
   TObjectContainer(TObjectContainer&&) = default;
   ~TObjectContainer()
     { for (lib_object* element : *this)
         (*freeInstance)(element);
     }

  private:
   void (*freeInstance)(lib_object *o);
};

typedef TObjectContainer<std::vector<lib_object*>> ObjectVector;
```

It does not use `unique_ptr` but it should basically do the job.

Note that your are likely to overload every removal method like `clear` to call `freeInstance` or `pop_back` to return your original `std::unique_ptr`.